# local variable assignment error, why?

Tags: python

I am getting the following error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_uarfcn' referenced before assignment`

However I have no idea why, I declare it the same way as `ran_update_uarfcn` and that variable works fine. Any ideas?

```
current_uarfcn = ""
ran_update_uarfcn = ""

def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
  def set_current_uarfcn(value):
      global current_uarfcn
      global ran_update_uarfcn
      current_uarfcn = value
      ran_update_uarfcn = "upd ap" + " " + access_point_id + " " + "uarfcn=" + current_uarfcn 
  set_current_uarfcn("11000")
  print ran_update_uarfcn
  print current_uarfcn
  return
```

edit: stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/a/b.py", line 460, in <module>
    ran_network_listen(ap_id, mode)
  File "/a/b.py", line 97, in ran_network_listen
    print current_uarfcn
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current_uarfcn' referenced before assignment
```

Called like so:

```
    # Network Listen
    if args.ap_id:
      ap_id = args.ap_id[0]
      mode = None
      if len(args.ap_id) == 2:
          mode =  args.ap_id[1]
      ran_network_listen(ap_id, mode)
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't exhibit that error.

Comment: Post a complete example that you have tested then.

Comment: Additionally, include the stacktrace and mark what line the error occured in.

Comment: This is the complete code that is called, I've added in the stack trace

Comment: The call is missing. Is the order of the statements correct? Does the function appear after the two lines at the top?

Comment: I put in the call, it is called from klish. there are imports then I declare these variables, then there are a few functions before this function.

Comment: The answer below works fine, however I don't know why I was getting one var working and one var not working, when they are used in the same way.

Comment: @phant0m I just changed the name of the variable by putting a 2 on the end and everything works fine. I have no explanation for this...

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: @invert I too think they are bad, but what is the alternative? I don't want to repeat the same code over and over.

Comment: It's difficult to see what you're trying to do, but generally you should pass in arguments instead of using globals. If your `set_current_uarfcn` is some kind of logging function, then use a decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code as **displayed** works fine.

The only problem I can think to is that you are using tabs on some lines and spaces on others so that the assignment statement is indeed part of the outer function.

With python you should never ever use tabs for your code (we have a pre-commit rule that actually enforces this)

Comment: I use `#!/usr/bin/python -tt`. I solved this by simply changing the name of the variable (adding a 2 on the end) and it works fine. I have no idea why. I changed it back and it works fine still. It's just weird.

Comment: It was probably something like this, just some misc error, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define ran_network_listen inside your first function

```
current_uarfcn = ""
ran_update_uarfcn = ""

def ran_network_listen(access_point_id, mode):
    global current_uarfcn
    global ran_update_uarfcn
    def set_current_uarfcn(value):
        current_uarfcn = value
        ran_update_uarfcn = "upd ap" + " " + access_point_id + " " + "uarfcn=" + current_uarfcn 
    set_current_uarfcn("11000")
    print ran_update_uarfcn
    print current_uarfcn
    return
```

Comment: There is no need to put a `global` declaration in a function where you only read the variable value (i.e. if there is no assignment).

Comment: This works fine thanks. although I don;t know why the behaviour I am seeing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to declare global also inside of ran_network_listen method?
You declared it only in the context inside of set_current_uarfcn.

Comment: Yes this works and I dont have to declare it in `set_current_uarfcn` then at all. However I want to know why one variable was working and one was not.

Comment: If you remove the one that is returning the error it won't come and error for the other?

Comment: Yup, no error for the other. The error has disappeared now. I just removed the variable and put in back in!

Comment: Nice it's working now :)